# How to use accelerometer in Garmin Fenix 3?

Tags: garmin, connectiq

Is there a way to use the accelerometer in Garmin Fenix 3? I am developing a Stroke Coach application for my Fenix 3 watch.

My issue is that I don't know how to utilize the accelerometer sensor that I know is in my watch. I have searched the documentation for developing Apps for all Garmin IQ compatible devices with no luck.

Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 6):

Accelerometer data is available as of the [v1.2.1 Connect IQ SDK release](http://developer.garmin.com/index.php/blog/post/announcing-connect-iq-1.2/). You can read the specifics about the API in the [online docs](http://developer.garmin.com/downloads/connect-iq/monkey-c/doc/Toybox/Sensor/Info.html#accel-instance_method), and there is also a simple AccelMag sample app included with the SDK that demonstrates the use of the accelerometer.

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no way to access the internal sensors of the watches. ANT+ Sensors are the only things exposed to apps in Toybox.

http://developer.garmin.com/downloads/connect-iq/monkey-c/doc/Toybox/Sensor.html

Comment: if so, how come there are apps that can access to pressure information? in other words, do you happen to know how can I access to this information? or how can I calculate depth underwater?